# Show timer on LCD ,AVR

Tags: avr, timing, atmega16

How to write a timer in c for avr  that shows below pic in each row on LCD ?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK1mE.jpg)

Comment: This depends on what LCD you have selected and how the ATmega16 is connected to the LCD.  Also, it's unlikely anyone will just do your whole project for you, so maybe you should make an attempt at it first and ask a more specific question when you get stuck.  You also should break this up into at least two questions: how to write to the LCD, and how to format a string in the "HH:MM:SS" format.  You might consider using an Arduino Uno because there are lots of LCD libraries for it already, so you wouldn't have to write much code.

Comment: Done it ,TNX David

Answer (score 0):

Refer this web page. It will tell how to do it
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/digital-alarm-clock-using-avr